# C# Change A Button's Background Color

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background

How can the background color of a button once another button is pressed?

What I have at the moment is:

```
ButtonToday.Background = Color.Red;
```

And it's not working.

Comment: Winform /WPF / SIlverlight/ASP.NET ?

Comment: `this.Button1.BackgroundColor = newColor`?

Comment: What code have you tried?  What platform are you on?  What makes you think you're missing a namespace?

Comment: It's a WPF using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: *And it's not working.* is not a sufficiently detailed description of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

WinForm:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

WPF:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   button2.Background = Brushes.Blue;
}
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that 'BackColor' is coming up with an error - red underlined in Visual Studio.

Comment: make sure you're 'using' System.Windows.Media.Brushes and not System.Drawing.Brush - (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx)

Comment: @Feroc is there a way to set the backcolor when the button is held down?

Comment: @CBC_NS: I guess you would need to change the color in the events MouseDown and MouseUp.

Answer (score 16):

In WPF, the background is not a `Color`, it is a `Brush`.  So, try this for starters:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

// ....

ButtonToday.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

More sensibly, though, you should probably look at doing this in your Xaml instead of in code.

Answer (score 5):

Code for set background color, for `SolidColor`:

```
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(Avalue, rValue, gValue, bValue));
```

Comment: Nice option to add custom colors versus system colors.

Comment: Also for those who are unfamiliar with the first overload like I was... it stands for the Alpha value 0 to 255 and determines transparency of background where 255 is completely solid: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
// WPF

// Defined Color
button1.Background = Brushes.Green;

// Color from RGB
button2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble at first with setting the colors for a WPF applications controls.
It appears it does not include `System.Windows.Media` by default but does include `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media`, which has some pre-filled colors.

I ended up using the following line of code to get it to work:

```
grid.Background.SetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, Windows.UI.Colors.CadetBlue);
```

You should be able to change `grid.Background` to most other controls and then change `CadetBlue` to  any of the other colors it provides.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if any of those should work.
Try:
First import the namespace in the beginning of the code page as below.

```
using System.Drawing;
```

then in the code.

```
Button4.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.button2.BaseColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(29)))), ((int)(((byte)(190)))), ((int)(((byte)(149)))));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Refrain from posting code-only answers and [edit] the post to contain an explanation as to why this solves the problem. Always remember that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to future readers, such as yourself. Especially when answering 9 year old questions.