# Windows Phone C# - Button color for button array

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've began by creating a large array of buttons, 1 to 96 on my program. The plan was that as one button was pressed it would turn red, which would randomly catch on other buttons near by.

The problem I have is that the button does not wish to turn red whatsoever. Below, I will show the code of my attempt to do so:

```
public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            numbers = new[] {
            button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10,
            button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19,
            button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, button25, button26, button27, button28,
            button29, button30, button31, button32, button33, button34, button35, button36, button37,
            button38, button39, button40, button41, button42, button43, button44, button45, button46,
            button47, button48, button49, button50, button51, button52, button53, button54, button55,
            button56, button57, button58, button59, button60, button61, button62, button63, button64,
            button65, button66, button67, button68, button69, button70, button71, button72, button73,
            button74, button75, button76, button77, button78, button79, button80, button81, button82,
            button83, button84, button85, button86, button87, button88, button89, button90, button91,
            button92, button93, button94, button95, button96
            };

        }

        private void ButtonSequence(int bRef)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int activeCell = bRef;
            int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10);
            int steps = 0;
            int randomMaxRange = 2;

            SolidColorBrush red = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            numbers[activeCell].Background = red;

                if (activeCell == 0)
                {
                    randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10);
                    if (randomNumber < randomMaxRange)
                    {
                        steps++;
                        ButtonSequence(1);
                    }
```

This function continues, and is called by:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonSequence(0);
}
```

And others.

Has anyone got a fix for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991041/c-sharp-change-a-buttons-background-color

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manually create 96 buttons in your application, you have something wrong with the way you handle your data model. Also, in your code, you are never actually adding the buttons to the page visual tree. Do you have a container for your data somewhere on your page?

You also don't seem to have the event handler tied to the UI control.

Comment: Haha, I know. It's my first day playing around with Windows Phone development. I usually use Python, so C# is new to me.
All buttons are called in the XML file if that is any help.

Comment: How exactly are you calling them in XML?