# How do I change dynamically a background color of a WPF:s button

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Goal:
Change dynamically the button's background color inside of my customized private function. The start point is

```
gridMain.Children.
```

Problem:
I tried googling and I read about class button and lots of different website but I cannot find a relevant clue in order to change the background color. My way of thinking is that the concept will be same as nhibernate's ability to edit data and then save it.

I need to retrieve a specific button from `gridMain.Children.` that has a name, btn_test, and change the background color and then to be saved.

Again, the problem is that I cannot find a relevant code to my purpose.

Info:
- I'm using VS 2013 with WPF and C#.
- Inside of gridMain.Children. I have a lot of button with different name. Buttons are created dynamically.

Comment: How about `button.Background = SomeNewColor` ?

Comment: **Right solution** : google, try things, if nothing works, ask here with what you've tried.  **Wrong solution** : ask for someone else to do it for you...

Comment: I tried before by using googling etc but I failed. Maybe I have not written enough in the problem statement.

Comment: "button.Background = SomeNewColor", In this context, it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarioStoilov: Definitely a duplicate. Please vote to close instead of just commenting.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't have the rep for that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var eelement = gridMain.Children
                       .OfType<Button>()
                       .Where(b => vb.Name.Equals(_buttonName))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
eelement.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Button1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

courtesy: Dan Puzey (From his answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991041/c-sharp-change-a-buttons-background-color) question)

Comment: If you notice this is a duplicate, please vote to close the question instead of contributing to spamming the site with duplicate information.

Comment: Flagged it. Thanks. @O.R.Mapper

Answer (score 0):

```
button.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

The WPF Button class has Background property, which needs to be set as a Brush.

Comment: Nor can you. [`System.Windows.Controls.Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) doesn't have a `BackColor` property. That's a WinForms thing.