# get button color - visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, button, colors

Using C# and Visual Studio 2010, I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991041/c-sharp-change-a-buttons-background-color) how can I set the button background color. But how can i get the button background color (and then put it in another button - change colors).

I already tried -

```
String c = button1.BackColor.getColor();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Color color = button2.BackColor;

button1.BackColor = color;
```

Or if you don't need the color anywhere else, you can set it directly.

```
button1.BackColor = button2.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

BackColor is a property that has a public get and set.

You need to change it to this.

```
using System.Drawing;

Color color = button1.BackColor;
```

The above is for winforms. You didn't specify what exactly you were using.

To store it as a string.

```
string color = button1.BackColor.ToString();
```

Comment: It write - Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Color' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\USER\Desktop\a\a\Form1.cs 22 34 a

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: @bar Sry it should be System.Drawing not windows.forms. That was my mess up. The above should work as long as you have using System.Drawing.

Comment: This is a better answer than the one marked as correct because it explains how properties work in dotnet.