# Get ListView item properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, uwp

I am adding items to my `ListView` manually. I am quite new to UWP and xaml.
This is my xaml and c# codes:

```
public sealed partial class CalendarFlyout : SettingsFlyout
{
    public CalendarFlyout()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Width = 450;
        for (int i = 0; i < GlobalVars.table.Count; i++)
        {
                calendarFlyout.Items.Add(new Items { Time = sSplit[0], Country = sSplit[1], Title = sSplit[2], Results = sSplit[3] + "|" + sSplit[4] + "|" + sSplit[5], FlagImage = imagePath, bull1 = images[0], bull2 = images[1], bull3 = images[2], Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen)});
        }
        //change background here
    }
}

public class Items
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Results {get; set; }
    public string FlagImage { get; set; }
    public string bull1 { get; set; }
    public string bull2 { get; set; }
    public string bull3 { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
}
```

xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="calendarFlyout" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="450"> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Name="bord1" BorderBrush="#FFCDCDCD" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Width="450" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="450" Height="50" Background="{Binding Color}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="timeText" Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="countryText" Text="{Binding Country}" Margin="65,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="newsText" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="120,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="resultText" Text="{Binding Results}" Margin="120,30,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Image Margin="0,15,440,0" Source="{Binding bull1}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <Image Margin="20,15,420,0" Source="{Binding bull2}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <Image Margin="40,15,400,0" Source="{Binding bull3}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <Image Name="flag" Margin="65,20,355,10" Source="{Binding FlagImage}" Stretch="Uniform"/>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I am trying to change the background color of specific item. How can I access that item? Is there a way to set the background color after that the item is created rather then when it is created?

Comment: See [C# Change A Button's Background Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991041/c-sharp-change-a-buttons-background-color) and [Set background color of WPF Textbox in C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979876/set-background-color-of-wpf-textbox-in-c-sharp-code). Do they help?

Comment: Can you access the Items object where you want to change the Color property in code or do you really need to access the Grid?

Comment: Use `Binding` which is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you could access an item of the ListView like this way:

```
Items targetItem= calendarFlyout.Items[2] as Items;
```

Then, if you want to change its background color by assigning the target Brush value to that item, you need make your model class implement the interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), so the definition of your model class would be like this:

```
public class Items : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Results { get; set; }
    public string FlagImage { get; set; }
    public string bull1 { get; set; }
    public string bull2 { get; set; }
    public string bull3 { get; set; }

    private Brush _brush;
    public Brush Color
    {
        get { return _brush; }
        set
        {
            _brush = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Finally, you could change its background color:

```
Items targetItem = calendarFlyout.Items[2] as Items;
targetItem.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Further more, as a suggestion, I think you'd better have a deeper leaning about INotifyPropertyChanged and MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

calendarFlyout.Items[2].BackColor = Color.Blue;