# WPF - How to set background color to image button

Tags: c#, wpf, background-image, background-color

I have a button with background image and I want to add a background color to this button when I click on it.

This is how I have set image background to button:

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="ScannerButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="ScannerButton_Click" Margin="0,0,5,25" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="/Resources/scanner.png"></Image>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

This is how I want it to look like when I click on it:

[image]

Comment: Should the background only for the moment when the user clicked the `Button` or should it be for longer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Change A Button's Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991041/c-sharp-change-a-buttons-background-color)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom until I click another button

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Duplicate?? Are you kidding me! Please read carefully my question!

Comment: @TestMan And? You need to change background to another color. Linked question's answer provide how to do it on `Button`'s click for `WPF` and `WinForm` !!!

Comment: @TestMan That makes it a bit more complicate; you should add this to your question. So you have to memorise which button you've pressed the last time. Could do this in the viewmodel and bound this property to the `Background` of the `Button` and using an `IMultiValueConverter` with for example the buttons name and the name of the button which is pressed for the last time to return the background-color in your converter.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I do not want to change background to another color!! I want to add background to button which already has a image for background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example make it a `ToggleButton` and add a trigger that changes the background when the `IsChecked` property is set to `true`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ScannerButton" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="ScannerButton_Click" Margin="0,0,5,25" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                <Image Source="/Resources/scanner.png"></Image>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="grid" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I get this error when I try to make it a ToggleButton: The member "IsChecked" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: Sorry, you also need to set the TargetType property of the ControlTemplate. I edited my answer.

Comment: Okay now it works! This is the answer what I was looking for. Thanks again!