# Having trouble changing buttons background

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to change the background of the buttons when a button is clicked it doesn't color the background of the button.

My attempt:

```cs
private void Ans1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //green the correct answer
    Ans1.Background = bc.ConvertFromString("#FF3C9C27") as SolidColorBrush;

    //rest all red
    Ans2.Background = bc.ConvertFromString("#FFAE2F2F") as SolidColorBrush;
    Ans3.Background = bc.ConvertFromString("#FFAE2F2F") as SolidColorBrush;
    Ans4.Background = bc.ConvertFromString("#FFAE2F2F") as SolidColorBrush;

    Thread.Sleep(1500);
}
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991041/c-sharp-change-a-buttons-background-color

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please post more of your code so we can retry in our conditions, `bc` variable could significant reason why. and can you also post error or exception it throws if any

Comment: Why the `Thread.Sleep(...)`, it blocks the UIThread from updating the ui (this may be your problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Change A Button's Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991041/c-sharp-change-a-buttons-background-color)

Comment: I have the thread.sleep because I want the user to see which of the answers is the correct one

Comment: @EmilKasyanov but due to the `Thread.Sleep` the user will likly don't see any change

Comment: @Ackdari so how can I fix that, I need a delay to show the user which answers are correct.

Comment: @EmilKasyanov: Please clarify your requirements. What outcome do you expect and what do you currently see?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Ans1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var button = sender as Button; <-- sender is the current button
     button.Background = bc.ConvertFromString("#FF3C9C27") as SolidColorBrush;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your conversion is the problem.
`bc.ConvertFromString("#FF3C9C27")` most likely returns a `System.Windows.Media.Color`.
`System.Windows.Media.Color as SolidColorBrush` returns null however.

This should give you the desired result:

```
private void Ans1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //green the correct answer
    Ans1.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)bc.ConvertFromString("#FF3C9C27"));

    //rest all red
    Ans2.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)bc.ConvertFromString("#FFAE2F2F"));
    Ans3.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)bc.ConvertFromString("#FFAE2F2F"));
    Ans4.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)bc.ConvertFromString("#FFAE2F2F"));
}
```

About the `Thread.Sleep` "issue": you could use a [Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) instead.

Answer (score -1):

To change the background color of your button, inside your clicked function that's been auto-generated add the following code:

```
                Ans1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                Ans2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Ans3.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Ans4.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `BackColor` is not a property of a WPF `Button`

Comment: Change Backcolor to Background

Comment: As other comments already said, `BackColor` doesn't exist for a WPF `Button` but `Color.Red` also doesn't exist here. For `System.Windows.Media.Color` the predefined colors are `Colors.Red`, `Colors.Green`, etc (also in `System.Windows.Media`)